# AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'calculateGrade'

Tags: python, class, python-requests, attributes, attributeerror

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, id, standard, phyMarks, chemMarks, mathsMarks):
        self.name = name 
        self.id = id
        self.standard = standard
        self.phyMarks = phyMarks
        self.chemMarks = chemMarks
        self.mathsMarks = mathsMarks

        def calculateGrade(Student):
            if self.phyMarks + self.chemMarks + self.mathsMarks >= 250:
                return "A"
            elif self.phyMarks + self.chemMarks + self.mathsMarks >= 150:
                return "B" 
            else:
                return "C"
        
        def  haspassed(Student): 
            if calculateGrade() == "C":
                return "Failed"
            else:
                return "Passed" 



Raghav = Student("Raghav", 1, 9, 23, 56, 10)
Madhav = Student("Madhav", 2, 9, 98, 79, 83)
Hemant = Student("Hemant", 3, 9, 99, 100, 100)
Harish = Student("Harish", 4, 9, 89, 72, 68)
Raunak = Student("Raunak", 5, 9, 100, 100, 100)

print("Student with name" , Raghav.name, Raghav.id, "has scored grade", Raghav.calculateGrade(), ".", "So his pass status is , ", Raghav.hasPassed())
print("Student with name" , Madhav.name, Madhav.id, "has scored grade", Madhav.calculateGrade(), ".", "So his pass status is , ", Madhav.hasPassed())
print("Student with name" , Raunak.name, Raunak.id, "has scored grade", Raunak.calculateGrade(), ".", "So his pass status is , ", Raunak.hasPassed())
```

I am not getting the calculateGrade and hasPassed attribute in the print statement. Please Help as I am given this homework. the given question was - Create a class with python named student give properties called name, id, standard, physicsMarks , chemistryMarks, mathsMarks define 2 methods calculateGrade() and hasPassed() if marks >=250 -> A if marks>= 150 -> B otherwise C if student has C grade he has failed, otherwise passed create atleast 5 instances
print("student with name" , shubham.name, and id: , shubham.id has scored grade shubham.calculateGrade(). So his pass status is shubham,hasPassed())

Comment: check your indentation

Comment: Due to indentation, you made that function a local function inside of `__init__`, not a method of the class. Fix the indentation so it's the same as `def __init__`. The same goes for `haspassed`.

Comment: What is your school's policy on getting SO to assist with your homework?

Comment: No this is not school hw. this is my tution hw, the teacher has no problem in taking assist from others.

Answer (score 1):

There are two points to consider. Indentation, and "self".

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, id, standard, phyMarks, chemMarks, mathsMarks):
        # do something

        def calculateGrade(Student):
           # do something

        def  haspassed(Student):
           # do something
```

Because `calculateGrade()` and `haspassed()` are indented too far, it becomes part of `__init__()`

Although it will work to use `Student` as the first parameter in the class functions, it is considered best practice to use the standard `self`.

Your code should look more like this:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, id, standard, phyMarks, chemMarks, mathsMarks):
        # do something

    def calculateGrade(self):
        # do something

    def haspassed(self):
        # do something
```

Edited to add:

Also, perhaps look at the question again. Not to do your homework for you, but to encourage you to think through the options.

> ...if student has C grade he has failed, otherwise passed.

> ...So his pass status is shubham.hasPassed()

This sounds like a true/false situation. If someone wants to make lots of calls to check the pass/fail status, they need to run the `calculateGrades()` function each time, which is extra processing. Would it make sense to have some other way of recording the outcome within the class? Just food for thought.